# Struts2 - disable conversion error

Tags: validation, struts2, struts-validation

I have a ssn field (represented as a String in Action class) in which the user enters something in the following format 123-23-2233. Struts2 throws an error. I dont know where it is configured for it to throw this as an error. How do I stop this?

I have my own validation in the validate() method, something like this

```
if(StringUtility.isBlank(person.getSsn()) || !validateRegex(SSN_REGEX,person.getSsn().trim())){
   this.addFieldError("person.ssn","SSN is required");
}
```

Comment: I assume the ssn is set to the person object.  What type is the ssn field in the person object? Need to see more code.

Comment: the ssn field is a string in the person object

Comment: What do you mean by 'Struts2 throws an error' do you mean throws an exception? If so what was the exception. Or do you mean adds a field error when you don't think it should?

Comment: Include your action code and any exceptions from your logs related to this.

Comment: Give us more information like the stacktrace for the error so we can help you

Answer (score 0):

The conversion errors will be added to the field errors map before your validate method even runs. As such there is a very simple way of removing them once you get to your validate method. Simply remove the error from the map before adding your own.

Example code below;

```
if(yourCondition){
   // Check whether this field has existing errors and remove them.
   List<String> existingErrors = getFieldErrors().get("person.ssn");
   if(existingErrors != null){
       existingErrors.clear();
   }       
   // Add your own error.
   addFieldError("person.ssn","SSN is required");
}
```

Similarly you could clear the entire field errors map if you wanted to clear the default error messages on all fields.

I hope this helps.